# How to make the background of my text larger?

Tags: html, css, layout

I display some text but not all of the text is shown so I want to make the background larger so that all the text displays. Right now the lower part of the "g" is outside the clipping area:

[image]

My HTML is

```
 <h2><strong>{% trans %}Why Bnano is{% endtrans %}</strong><span>{% trans %}RIGHT FOR YOU{% endtrans %}</span></h2>
```

And my CSS is

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, caption, hr, button {margin:0; padding:0; border:0; outline:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align: baseline; background:none;}
table, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {padding:4px;vertical-align:top;}
ol, ul {list-style:none;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, li {line-height:100%;}
blockquote, q {quotes:none;}
q:before,
q:after {content: '';}
table {border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing:0;}
input, textarea, select{
    font:11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
form, fieldset{border-style:none;}
html {height:100%;}
body {
    min-width:1004px;
    color:#404344;
    height:100%;
    font:13px/16px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background:#fff;
    margin: 0 1px 1px;
}
img{border-style:none;}
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
a:focus {outline:none;}
a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
/* wrapper */
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
* html #wrapper {height:100%;}
/* header */
#header {
    width:100%;
    background:#1596c3 url(/welcome/static/images/bg-header.png) repeat-x;
}
#header:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
/* header-area */
.header-area {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:948px;
    padding:0 23px;
}
/* top-panel*/
.top-panel {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:36px;
    padding:6px 0 0 4px;
    margin:0 0 19px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9999999 !important;
}
/* search-form */
.search-form {
    float:right;
    margin:0 10px 0 15px;
}
.search-form form {float:left;}
.top-panel .text {
    float:left;
    padding:6px 13px 7px 13px;
    margin:0 5px 0 0;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-text.gif) no-repeat;
}
.top-panel .text input {
    font:13px "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#8cc0d3;
    float:left;
    width:157px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 -2px 0 0;
    border:0;
    background:none;
}
.top-panel .text input:focus {outline:none;}
.search-form .search {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/btn-search.gif) no-repeat;
    width:26px;
    height:27px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0;
}
/* email-form */
.email-form {
    float:left;
    width:214px;
}
.email-form form {float:left;}
.email-form .go {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/btn-go.gif) no-repeat;
    width:26px;
    height:27px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    line-height:0;
    font-size:0;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:0;
}
/* links */
.top-panel .links {
    float:right;
    padding:9px 0 0;
    width:410px;
}
.top-panel .links .title {
    float:left;
    color:#fdfdfd;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:13px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.top-panel .links .title .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
.top-panel .links ul {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:-5px 0 0;
}
.top-panel .links li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 9px;
}
.top-panel .links li img {display:block;}
/* header-info */
.header-info {
    padding:0 0 95px 17px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999 !important;
}
/* logo */
.logo {
    float:left;
    background:url(/welcome/static/images/logo-opaque1.png) no-repeat;
    width:290px;
    height:176px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    margin:0 0 0 -15px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}
.logo a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
/* nav */
#nav {
    float:right;
    padding:20px 0 0;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    margin:0 3px 0 3px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:17px;
}
#nav li a {
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px 0 0;
    color:#a9cfdd;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#nav li a span {
    float:left;
    padding:5px 6px 4px 11px;
}
#nav li.active a,
#nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f6f6f6;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/btn-active.gif) no-repeat 100% -23px;
}
#nav li.active a span,
#nav li a:hover span {
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/btn-active.gif) no-repeat;
}
#nav li a .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
/* info-area */
#header .info-area {
    height:398px;
    width:900px;
    background:none !important;
    padding:15px 2px 0 13px;
    margin-top:-148px;
    margin-left:25px;
}

#header .info-area .txt {
    float:left;
    color:#f6f8f9;
    font-size:19px;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text .cufon {margin-top:1px !important;}
#header .info-area .title {
    color:#a9cfdd;
    font-size:48px;
    position:absolute;
    line-height:51px;
    padding-top:55px;
    width:550px;
}
#header .info-area .title span {
    font-size:35px;
    line-height:36px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:32px !important;
    padding-top:1px;
}
#header .info-area .title em {
    font-style:normal;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:53px !important;
}
#header .info-area .desc {
    font-family: "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
    line-height:20px;
    margin: 8px 0 25px 3px;
    font-size:19px;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999 !important;
    padding-top:130px;
    width:550px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    padding:0 0 5px;
}
#header .info-area .txt .text1 {
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/ico03.gif) no-repeat 2px 9px;
    padding:26px 0 27px 114px;
}
#header .info-area .img {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:500px;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
#header .info-area .more {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:25px;
    letter-spacing:1px !important;
    margin-top:23px;
    margin-left:-3px;
}
#header .info-area .more a {
    color:#f6f8f9;
    float:left;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet05.gif) no-repeat 5px 3px;
    padding:0 0 0 19px;
    font-size:18px;
}
#header .info-area .more a span {
    float:left;
    margin-left:-2px;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
#header .info-area .more a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#header .info-area .more a:hover span {
    border-bottom:1px solid #f6f8f9;
    padding:0;
}
/* main */
#main {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:58px 0 122px;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-main-area.gif) repeat-x;
}
/* onecolumn */
#onecolumn {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1004px;
    position:relative;
}
#onecolumn ul {
    margin:10px 0 10px 25px;
}
#onecolumn li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
#onecolumn  h2 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 8px 0;

}
#onecolumn  h2 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#onecolumn  h2 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#onecolumn  h2 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#onecolumn  h3 {
    color:#676a6b;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#onecolumn  h3 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#onecolumn  h3 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
}
#onecolumn  h3 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#onecolumn .content {
    padding:0 48px 10px 48px;
}
#onecolumn content p {margin:0 0 16px;}
/* twocolumns */
#twocolumns {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:1004px;
    position:relative;
}
#twocolumns h2 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 14px 0;
}
#twocolumns h2 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#twocolumns h2 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
    font-size:30px;
}
#twocolumns h2 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#twocolumns h3 {
    color:#062f3d;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:26px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 10px;
}
#twocolumns h3 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}
#twocolumns h3 span {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:-3px 0 0;
    font-size:26px;
}
#twocolumns h3 .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#twocolumns h4 strong {
    color:#138db7;
    font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 10px 0 17px 2px;
}
/* content */
#content {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:596px;
    padding:0 20px 10px 48px;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
#content p {
    margin:0 2px 16px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size:13px;
}
#content p img {
    padding:10px;
}
#content .more {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    padding:0 0 16px 4px;
    font-size:14px;
}
#content .more a {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet01.gif) no-repeat 0 55%;
    padding:0 0 0 13px;
    color:#404344;
}
#content .more a:hover {
    color:#138db7;
}
/* video-block */
#content .video-block {
    width:616px;
    margin:0 -20px 0 -19px;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 4px 0 15px;
    background:#d4dadb url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-video-block.gif) repeat-x;
}
#content .video-block:after {
    display:block;
    clear:both;
    content:"";
}
#content .video-block .heading {
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-heading.gif) no-repeat;
    width:176px;
    height:51px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 0 4px -7px;
    padding:25px 0 0 15px;
}
#content .video-block .info-col {
    float:left;
    width:271px;
    padding:0 0 0 7px;
    margin:-6px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#content .video-block h3 {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    padding:3px 0 0;
    margin:0;
}
#twocolumns .video-block strong {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
}
#twocolumns .video-block span{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    display:inline;
    font-size:25px;
    color:#fff;
}
/* list */
#content .video-block .list {height:1%;}
#content .video-block .list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 13px 13px;
    line-height:14px;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet02.gif) no-repeat 1px 4px;
}
#content .video-block .list li h4 {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#967723;
}
#content .video-block .list li h4 a {color:#967723;}
#content .video-block .list li p {margin:0;}
#content .video-block .video {
    float:right;
    margin:0 0 -8px;
    padding:30px 0 0;
    position:relative;
}
#content .video-block .video img {display:block;}
#content blockquote {
  font: 14px/22px normal helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-left: 3px solid #ccc;
}
#content blockquote p {margin:0;}
#content blockquote cite {font-style:normal;}
/* blocks */
#content .blocks {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:582px;
}
#content .blocks h3 {
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:18px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#4499b7;
    margin:0 0 13px;
}
#content .block-holder {
    width:590px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0 -8px 5px 0;
}
#content .blocks .block {
    width:290px;
    margin:0 4px 0 0;
    padding:18px 0 10px;
    float:left;
    color:#ba9d50;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:13px;
    background:#dcddde;
}
#content .blocks .block .img {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 0 18px;
}
#content .blocks .block .img img {vertical-align:top;}
#content .blocks .block p {
    text-align:center;
    margin:0;
}
#content .blocks .block p a {color:#ba9d50;}
#content ul {
    margin:10px 0 10px 25px;
}
#content li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:16px;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
/* sidebar */
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    width:315px;
    padding:0 3px 0 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
#sidebar p {
    margin-left:2px;
}
/* news-list */
#sidebar .news-list {
    width:300px;
    padding:0 15px 19px 0;
}
#sidebar .news-list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    vertical-align:top;
    padding:0 0 12px 15px;
    line-height:14px;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet03.gif) no-repeat 2px 6px;
}
#sidebar .news-list li h4 {
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:0 0 1px;
}
/* news-list1 */
#sidebar .news-list1 {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-bottom:14px;
    width:300px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 li {
    background-position:3px 6px;
    padding-left:17px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 h4 {
    color:#967723;
    position:relative;
    word-spacing:-1px;
}
#sidebar .news-list1 h4 a {color:#967723;}
/* #sidebar .news-list1 h4 a {color:#967723;} */
/* info-list */
#sidebar .info-list {
    width:269px;
    padding:1px 0 0;
}
#sidebar .info-list li {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1%;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height:27px;
    margin:0 0 2px;
    vertical-align:top;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-info-list.gif) no-repeat;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a {
    float:left;
    padding:9px 10px 4px 41px;
    color:#138db7;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bullet04.gif) no-repeat 13px 50%;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
#sidebar .info-list li a span {
    float:left;
    margin:0 2px 0 0;
}
#sidebar .info-list li a strong {float:left;}
#sidebar .view {
    display:block;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/assets/files/img/btn/online-store.png) no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:30px;
    width:191px;
    height:75px;
    margin:0 0 0 -8px;
    padding:22px 115px 0 18px;
}
#sidebar .view span {
    font-size:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar .view strong {
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar .view .cufon {
    float:left;
    margin:0 !important;
}
#sidebar .view:hover {text-decoration:none;}
/* footer */
#footer {
    height:206px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:-106px 0 0;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#9ddbf1;
    background:#1494c1 url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-footer.gif) repeat-x;
}
/* footer-area */
.footer-area {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:948px;
    padding:52px 1px 0;
}
.footer-area p a {color:#000000;}
#footer .copyright {
    float:left;
    width:390px;
    margin:5px 30px 0 0;
}
#footer .copyright p {text-align:right;}
#footer .logo1 {
    float:left;
    background:url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/logo01.png) no-repeat;
    width:130px;
    height:102px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    position:relative;
    margin:-52px 30px 0 0;
}
#footer .logo1 a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}
/* info */
#footer .info {
    float:left;
    width:350px;
    position:relative;
    margin:-9px 0 0;
}
#sidebar form { 
width : 295px;
height : auto; 
text-align : left; 
margin-top : 10px;
margin-bottom:25px;
border: none;
}

#sidebar input { 
width : 240px; 
height:20px;
background : url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/bg-input.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
color : #666; 
font-size : 14px; 
margin-bottom : 6px; 
padding : 10px 10px 8px 10px;
border:0;
}

#sidebar textarea { 
width : 265px; 
height : 105px;
background : url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/textarea-b.png) no-repeat scroll 0% 0%; 
padding : 10px 30px 10px 10px; 
font-size : 14px; 
color : #666; 
margin-bottom : 1px;
border:0;
}

#sidebar .button { 
background : url(http://bnano-www.appspot.com/welcome/static/images/button.png) no-repeat 0% 0%; 
width : 104px; 
height : 30px; 
color : #fff; 
font-size : 13px; 
cursor:pointer;
margin-top:10px;
margin-left:180px;
padding : 5px 0 5px 0;
border:0;
font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

#sidebar .invalidValue { 
color:#c21313;
}
```

Can you tell me how I increase the drawing area?

Thanks

Comment: try increasing the padding to the container, in this case h2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to increase the `line-height` of your `<h2>`!

Answer (score 1):

Like Jannis M said, it is quite dirty... maybe you can show us more of the html, so it would be easier to understand and to help...

Answer (score 0):

You can add /increase padding to your `<h2>`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue cannot be observed using the code posted. Instead of a short fragment of server-side code, you should post the actual HTML code, which is probably something like

```
<h2><strong>Varför Bnano är</strong><span>rätt för dig</span></h2>
```

presumably inside an element with `id=onecolumn`. But what else? Even in this setting, the rendering is different.

In any case, the issue is most probably caused by setting an unsuitable `line-height` value on an element. For fonts like Lucida Sans Unicode and Lucida Grande, the value should be around 1.3 or a little larger – now one of the CSS rules sets the value to 100%, which means the font size of the parent element, and this is surely too little for `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

The text is cut because you have set the parent container size and set overflow: hidden; Inspect the dom and see what's the parent's element height; You have not given the full html so i can tell you where is the exact problem.

Start with:

## onecolumn